# laravel - How to concatenate URL and retrieve images from database in json format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display json array of the images stored in database to come with the full URL in Laravel. I am using `CONCAT()` function to concatenate the full URL of the image, but I'm getting a false URL with many dashes inside. 
This is a problem in the coming output:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695371.jpg"
  }, {
    "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695156.jpg"
  }, {
    "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509696465.jpg"
  }, {
    "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509697249.jpg"
  }]
}
```

And this is the function in my controller to retrieve the images stored in database from Post table:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::select(array(DB::raw("CONCAT('http://localhost:8000/images/', image) AS imageurl")))->get();
    return response()->json(['posts' =>  $posts]);
}
```

Any help will be more appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much @Sari It's now working fine. After changing the codes to this,

```
public function index()
{
  $posts =  json_encode(Post::select(array(DB::raw("CONCAT('http://localhost:8000/images/', image) AS imageurl")))->get(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

   return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing it at the db level you could do the following in your `Post` model

```
 public function getImageUrlAttribute($value)
    {
        return 'http://localhost:8000/'.$this->image;
    }
```

and access it like `$post->image_url`

Comment: Thanks Sari, but your answer is not solving the problem. I would like to know how to concatenate well without getting those additional dashes or to get a full url attached to image filename that i am retrieving

Comment: i am not seeing any dashes in the response sorry not sure what you mean @Hervera

Comment: thats not a db issue your code above should work fine.  you could jist simply do `return $posts` and i believe laravel takes care of JSON_UNESCAPE_SLASHES flag for you. your problem is that php is escaping your json response.

Comment: yeah i saw that you updated it. the json is escaped just add the flag referenced above

Comment: I am doing that as you've said  return $posts; but the same problem occurs, laravel doesn't escape the JSON_UNESCAPE_SLASHES flag. This is the new response [{
  "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695371.jpg"
}, {
  "imageurl": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695156.jpg"
}]

Comment: you can do the following    ` $posts = json_encode(Post::select(array(DB::raw("CONCAT('http://localhost:8000/images/', image) AS imageurl")))->get(),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: Thank you so much @Sari It's now working fine. After changing the codes to this   `public function index()
  {
      $posts =  json_encode(Post::select(array(DB::raw("CONCAT('http://localhost:8000/images/', image) AS imageurl")))->get(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

      return $posts;
  }`

Comment: my pleasure  i suggest creating an answer with the solution and posting it in here

Comment: Thanks, Let me do it to help others.

Answer (score 0):

DB::raw('CONCAT(\'http://localhost/hrms/images/logo/\', schools.image) as image')

And for dynamic use

DB::raw('CONCAT(\''.$url.'\', schools.image) as image')